# CSS File conflict from SPD and browser

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

After the major publishing-overwrite in SPD am confuse why the CSS file from browser contains the updated lines while the CSS file from SPD is old version. The checkbox in SPD file remains and republishing it shows an error:

> We cant do that for you because the file no longer checked out or has
>   been deleted.

Any thought will be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: This is a known issue with sharepoint designer 2010/2013. Try clearing all the local spd cache and try again. Try the steps in the mentioned  http://blah.winsmarts.com/2015-3-Clear_SharePoint_Designer_2013_Cache.aspx

Comment: A known issue since 2010 and MS has no say till now.. Anyway the clearing of cache work like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What i understand is that you getting error while you check in/out CSS file in SharePoint Designer.

You should try,

1. Go to your css file location in SharePoint UI-browser and try to check in or check out the file.
2. Clear SharePoint Designer Cache.
3. Refresh SharePoint Designer.